# Java won't complete downloading a zip file

Tags: java, download

I'm making a application in Java that download a file from a webserver. This file is a 816kb zip file. I've tested the application on 3 different computers and it isn't working for one computer. For that one it downloads only 13kb of the file and then stops. When I check the htaccess logs I see this:

a: "GET /cache.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 816938 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_07"

b: "GET /cache.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 134320 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.7.0_09"

(PC a is working, PC b isn't working)

I've tried lots of different ways to download the file in java but for all ways it stops downloading after 13kb. I've also tried to run te application with 512m memory but that isn't the problem.

This is what I have now:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Config.CACHE_DIR+File.separator+"cache.zip")));
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

while((count = in.read(data,0,1024)) >= 0){
    out.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

but this while loop won't stop so it gets stuck in `in.read`

Comment: java will not affect what's on the server. given you've got two same-url requests producing two different sized responses, something else is going on.

Comment: Put your code in a try-catch-block and let a possible exception print the stack trace, so we will know whether there is a problem.

Comment: Already did, but there are no errors. Its just waiting for in.read

Comment: According to the documentation for DataInputStream.read(...): "This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown." It seems to be a connection/transmission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a simple standalone test, to make sure the problem is with the PC and not your software:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Scratch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://url.to.zip");

    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Apache Commons IO [IOUtils.copy()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) for copying between streams. It uses a buffer to copy bytes from one stream to another.

By the way, there's no need to use a **Data**InputStream and DataOutputStream wrappers in your case. You can just use the InputStream and FileOutputStream directly.

With IOUtils, the code will become:

```
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
File outputFile = new File(Config.CACHE_DIR + File.separator + "cache.zip");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
try {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
} finally {
    output.close();
}
```

If you don't want to use IOUtils...

```
int count;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((count = in.read(data)) > 0) {
     out.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking for a solution without making use of external libaries.

Comment: Updated to give an answer without libraries.

Comment: Tried it but isn't workin. I've also tried the NIO methods but is also not working. I think its a problem on the pc that tries to download it because it is working on 2 pc`s and isn't working on 1 pc.